# Prevent creating relation model in factory if foreign id passed as attribute

Tags: laravel, factory, laravel-5.6

Lets's assume this factory:

**PostFactory.php**

```
$factory->define(Post::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title'=>$faker->word,
        'user_id'=>factory(User::class)->create()->id
    ];
});
```

then i use it like this:

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
factory(Post::class, 5)->create(['user_id'=>$user->id]);
```

I expect that 1 user and 5 posts will be created. But actually there are 6 users in database because `PostFactory` creates user whether `user_id` is passed or not.

Is there a way to prevent creating new user if `user_id` attribute passed to `create` method?

Comment: You're already creating users within the `Post` factory with `'user_id'=>factory(User::class)->create()->id`. So you're going to get 5 users with each of the posts and then an additional one you're creating afterwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a workaround for this.

```
$factory->define(Post::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title'=>$faker->word,
        'user_id'=> function () { return factory(User::class)->create()->id; }
    ];
});
```

Laravel is calling the `value()` helper when merging the attributes. If the `user_id` exists in the attributes it will not execute the callback, otherwise, it will.

You can see it in the doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#relationships) with exactly the same models as yours.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. I read this in docs but I didn't know that Laravel merge attributes like this.

Answer (score 0):

For Larave 5.1, you will need to pass the parameter and manually check if id is passed.

Here is the discussion regarding the issue. 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9245

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function ($faker, $attributes) {

$accountId = isset($attributes['account_id']) ? $attributes['account_id']: factory(App\Account::class)->create()->id;

return [
    'account_id' => $accountId,
    'email' => $faker->email,
    'password' => 'secret',
    'name' => $faker->name
];
```

});